# Which method is better? Void with out parameter or returning data?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm curious if there is a preferred approach to my problem. Basically, I have some data (it's xml) and I need to amend the data to add some attributes lets say. For this I have written a method to do it for me. Then I need to use the modded data later. Should the method return void or the required data type?

**Option 1:**

```
var someData = GetTheData();
someData = ModifyTheData(someData);
```

**Option 2:**

```
var someData = GetTheData();
ModifyTheData(someData, out someData);
```

Are there any differences between using these 2 versions? Would I be right in thinking that option 1 would create 2 instances in memory (1 for the someData variable and 1 for the return value of the method) but option 2 would only have 1 instance?

Is there a preferred approach? It doesn't matter too much, I'm just curious

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm always avoiding assignig values in methods, for me returning is much more clear.

Comment: I will prefer `someData = ModifyTheData(GetTheData());` instead, no need to create extra temp variables, better for interpreter languages, essay to use, single step, small code.

Comment: "Duplicate" of Code analysis warning [CA1021: Avoid out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx)

Comment: Thanks all and cheers for the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would I be right in thinking that option 1 would create 2 instances in memory (1 for the someData variable and 1 for the return value of the method) but option 2 would only have 1 instance?

That would depend on the implementation of the `ModifyTheData` method and whether the type of someData is reference or value type. If you only assign the `out` variable to the first argument both will be equivalent if `someData` is a reference type:

```
public void ModifyTheData(SomeData someData, out SomeData data)
{
    someData.Foo = "bar";
    data = someData;
}
```

is the same as:

```
public SomeData ModifyTheData(SomeData someData)
{
    someData.Foo = "bar";
    return someData;
}
```

is the same as:

```
public void ModifyTheData(SomeData someData)
{
    someData.Foo = "bar";
}
```

Comment: +1 Returning `void` is probably the most honest option for function that is called "ModifyTheData" (assuming it modifies "the data" in-place)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I like your last version, might use that. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to avoid out parameters as much as possible.
In your case, I think it is better to return the modified data.  It is imho more readable and more comprehensive.